# High Load average on Linux machine

Tags: php, linux, apache, amazon-web-services

I have a PHP application to provide virtual labs for C Programming.

It runs on an AWS m4.large type instance which is having 100% cpu utilization and very high load average,almost all the time.Below are the top 2 cpu intensive processes given by top command(these are the C compilation processes):

```
24982 apache 20 0 6504 504 420 R 99.9 0.0 409:36.82 a.out
24611 apache 20 0 6504 500 416 R 99.5 0.0 411:13.45 a.out
```

Both of these processes are using almost 100% cpu. Now running on lsof -p pid command for these 2 processes,I got

```
a.out 24611 apache mem REG 202,1 1920936 264214 /lib64/libc-2.12.so
a.out 24611 apache mem REG 202,1 596272 264222 /lib64/libm-2.12.so
a.out 24611 apache mem REG 202,1 154664 264207 /lib64/ld-2.12.so
```

and

```
a.out 24982 apache mem REG 202,1 1920936 264214 /lib64/libc-2.12.so
a.out 24982 apache mem REG 202,1 596272 264222 /lib64/libm-2.12.so
a.out 24982 apache mem REG 202,1 154664 264207 /lib64/ld-2.12.so
```

strace command output is filled with these lines

```
write(1, " Mode= 0 Mode= 0 Mode= 0 Mode= 0"..., 4096) = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
--- SIGPIPE {si_signo=SIGPIPE, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=24611, si_uid=48} ---
```

Need to know the reason for the high load average and cpu utilization.

Comment: are you sure those are compiler processes? a.out would be the output of the compiler, so looks like the compiled program is running. probably some bad code that is looping endlessly. you should probably make sure processes get killed if they run too long.

Comment: You can install htop and sort process by CPU %